# Linked List on C++

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I am learning Linked Lists at my school, but my professor did not specify many things..

first is a linked list a build in library?
the programmer needs to create a node class?

this is the only example i have:

```
class node;
typedef node*  nodeptr;

class node {
   public:
      int number;
      nodeptr next;
 };

//--------------------------------
int main ( ) 
{
   nodeptr top;
```

I do not know also what "typedef" means.. I do know what a pointer is.. I would appreciate if someone can explain a little bit of whats on ..

Comment: As for the typedef: it's basically assigning a different name to the mentioned data type. Much like: #define superInt __int64

Comment: Yes, the standard library contains both a singly and a doubly linked list, respectively called `std::forward_list` and `std::list`. For understanding `typedef`, continue attending your class?

Comment: @KerrekSB superb advice of yours ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First is a linked list a build in library?

Well, no. A linked list is a *data structure*. The standard library has two different implementation of it in `std::list` and `std::forward_list`.

---

> The programmer needs to create a node class

From the example above it seems your professor wants you to.

---

> I do not know also what "typedef" means.

`typedef` is a keyword. Its purpose is to assign alternative names to existing types. So for example to call `double` with another name (let's say `x`) you would go with something like the following:

```
typedef double x
```

Now you would be able to declare:

```
x name = 13.2
```

that would be translated into:

```
double name = 13.2
```

---

> I do know what a pointer is.

A pointer is a data type whose value can be an address to a specific memory space. In C++ to get the address of a specific allocated variable you would use `&x` where `x` is the allocated variable. Printing `&a` would print a memory address in the form of `0x...`. If you declare a variable with type `T*` you can make that variable contain a memory address of a variable of the same type `T`. The `*` sign in front of a pointer means *deferencing* the pointer which means *getting the value of the memory space it points to*.

```
int x = 10
int* y = &x
std::cout << (*y);
```

In the above example the output is `10`.

---

> I would appreciate if someone can explain a little bit of whats on.

A linked list, in its simplest form, can be implemented like the following:

```
struct node {
      node( x, y = 0 ) : field(x), next(y) {}
      int field;
      node* next;
};
```

A linked list serves the purpose of having a *dynamic container* with as many *cells* as it exactly needs. The idea behind it is that the main `node` structure should contain a member variable `field` that would store a single specific value and a pointer to the next `node` that will contain another value and so on.

A graphic representation can be the following:

```
[ a:10 ] ---> [ b:3 ] ---> [ c:7 ]
```

In the above example the node structure would be:

```
node c = node(7, 0);
node b = node(3, &c);
node a = node(10, &b);
```

where `0` means *null pointer* and is a special value that refers to "pointing to nothing".

Comment: I loved how you answered the question, "It seems your professor wants you to do that" ! :P

Answer (score 0):

The `typedef` keyword provides a means of creating a new type name from an existing type. Often `typedef` is used to simplify code by creating a new type name with a less confusing name than the original type.

In your case the existing type `node *` is used to create a new type name `nodeptr`.
Because of the typedef statement `nodeptr` can be used in place of `node *` as a type name.

```
typedef node* nodeptr;
```

The `node` class below has a data member `next` which has type name `nodeptr`. next has type of  `node` pointer (AKA nodeptr).

```
class node 
{ public: 
     int number; 
     nodeptr next; 
};
```